# init.lua:389: module 'hdf5' not found:No LuaRocks module found for hdf5

Tags: lua, hdf5, luarocks

when I do `require"hdf5"`I met error as follows:

```
/home/xus/torch/install/bin/luajit: /home/xus/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: module 'usr/local/hdf5' not found:No LuaRocks module found for usr/local/hdf5
    no field package.preload['usr/local/hdf5']
    no file '/home/supermicro/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/usr/local/hdf5.lua'
    ...
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/usr/local/hdf5.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /home/xus/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: in function 'require'
    prepro_img.lua:10: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    .../xus/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00405d50
```

Anyone can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

because you don't install hdf5, you can do
luarocks install hdf5